# How can I get old String object value once current object modified

Tags: java

If String is immutable object , whenever we modify a String object it will create another instance i.e. in memory we have two objects currently. How can I get value of first initialized value?

```
public class MutableVsImmutable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1 = new String("Dilip");

        System.out.println(str1.hashCode());
        str1 = str1 + " Singh";
        System.out.println(str1.hashCode());

        **// Here I want to get first initialized value of "str1" i.e. "Dilip"** 

    }

}
```

Comment: Cut off the part you appended there. If it is random, then you can't get the old string back.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable in java so when you manipulate the string,a new object is created and reference to the previous object is lost.there is no way to recover it.Java provides StringBuffer and StringBuilder to deal with this kind of  situation.important thing to note is no new object is created when you manipulate StringBuilder object.you can use it like this

```
StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder("Dilip");
System.out.println(str1.hashCode());
str1 = str1 + " Singh";
System.out.println(str1.hashCode());
```

Comment: if i am using StringBuffer or StringBuilder i.e. mutable classes, whenever we modified it will override current object.  So then there is no question to get old value.

Comment: If old reference is lost , then what is the use of creating new reference for every modification? In that case unnecessarly memory utilization is happening for some time if i am right.

Comment: since string is immutable and final in java (it has its own advantages),there is no way to modify it.java deals with it in its own way by creating new object.of course it creates unnecessary overhead and that's why it is advisable to use mutable classes while working with string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply mantain a reference to the old String

```
String orig = "ORIG";
String anotherOrigReference = orig;
orig = "CHANGED";
System.out.println(orig); // Prints CHANGED
System.out.println(anotherOrigReference); // PRints ORIG
```

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable, string reference variable is not. As long as you don’t reassign your reference variable to a new value you can get the initial assigned value(here Java in example).

Consider the below example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String sref = "java";

    sref.concat(" rules");

    // sref still refers to "java"

    System.out.println("sref refers to " + sref);
}
```

Here you will get : sref refers to java.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this simple?
If you want to keep a value don't overwrite it. Just introduce new variables for new values you need.

```
public class MutableVsImmutable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1 = new String("Dilip");

        System.out.println(str1.hashCode());
        String str2 = str1 + " Singh"; //Don't overwrite str1.
        System.out.println(str2.hashCode());

        System.out.println(str1); //str1 is still there and unchanged.  

    }

}
```